# Why is every number prime?

Tags: python, primes

Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep

n = 5
k = 2
found_factors = 0

while True:
   kinn = n/k

    if (n == k) and found_factors == 0:
        print("Found prime:", n)
        n += 1
        k = 2
        found_factors = 0
        sleep(0.1)
        continue
    elif (n == k) and found_factors > 0:
        n += 1
        k = 2
        found_factors = 0
        continue


    if isinstance(kinn, int) == True:
        found_factors += 1

    k += 1
```

The program is meant to find prime numbers, starting at 5. But for some reason, it outputs every number as a prime one!

Why is this happening?

Comment: Python 2 or 3? `5 / 2` doesn't do what you think it does in python 2

Comment: `isinstance(kinn, int)` doesn't test what you think it tests. If you want a divisibility test, that's `if n % k == 0`, testing the remainder.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you probably want `5 // 2`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode to figure out what the problem is yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n/k` always returns a float, even if `k` divides `n`, so for example `6/2` is `3.0` which is a `float`, and isn't an instance of `int`, however, there is another way to check if a number is an integer, using the modulo operator `%` between `n` and `k` to get the remainder of the division:

```
if n % k == 0:
        found_factors += 1
```

By replacing it in your program, it outputs:

```
Found prime: 5
Found prime: 7
Found prime: 11
Found prime: 13
Found prime: 17
Found prime: 19
Found prime: 23
Found prime: 29
Found prime: 31
Found prime: 37
Found prime: 41
Found prime: 43
Found prime: 47
Found prime: 53
Found prime: 59
Found prime: 61
Found prime: 67
# ........ more
```

Comment: nope, float doesn't generally work like this. For small integers, that might work, but for large ones, it won't. Your answer is hence w.l.o.g. wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You're right, I updated my answer now, I'm using `.is_integer()`.

Comment: @pagie_ You should use `.is_integer()`, it's more secure.

Comment: @pagie_ no, it doesn't work, or only for small numbers. again, this is not how floats work. For example, take `(float(2**112)+0.5).is_integer()==True`, although 2**112+0.5 definitely is not an integer.

Comment: Trying to determine whether the ratio of two integers is an integer just to determine whether one divides the other is kind of strange, considering python has a modulo operator for ints...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks again for the information, I, again, updated my answer to use the modulo operator, I hope that's flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep

n = 5.0 # change one of n/k to float so division will not truncate
k = 2
found_factors = 0

while True:
   kinn = n/k # note: in python 2 dividing ints truncates the remainder

    if (n == k) and found_factors == 0:
        print("Found prime:", n)
        n += 1
        k = 2
        found_factors = 0
        sleep(0.1)
        continue
    elif (n == k) and found_factors > 0:
        n += 1
        k = 2
        found_factors = 0
        continue

    # kinn used to truncate to an int, which is why this statement was always hit.
    # By changing the type of n to float, we test for remainder of n/k instead
    if n % k == 0:
        found_factors += 1

    k += 1
```